# How to find out if event listener paste was added to window?

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener

I want to add the event listener `paste` to `window` for a React SPA. So how do I find out if it was already added?

If this is not possible, can I get around using a `ref` that stores if this rendering of the page was the first time and the listener has to be added vs. was already added?